# How can I add jqueries to blogger mobile template?

Tags: jquery, templates, mobile, blogger

Ok so that's my trouble, reading in many pages I achieved to make semi-responsive my blog, but I need that gets fit on mobile devices, reading I knew that if custom theme it's not active you have to modify.

`b:if cond='data:blog.isMobile != &quot;true&quot;'` and then apply style text/css, but the up code it's not available, help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`isMobile` does't exist in layout version 3. Use `isMobileRequest`

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.isMobileRequest != "true"'>
    <!-- Your code here -->
</b:if>
```

Comment: thanks for your support @Bassam, so where do I have to write it in the template?

Comment: Hi! Use it anywhere inside your template. it works.